# Exposing a Javascript object as a module in webpack

Tags: configuration, build, webpack

Inside `webpack.config.js` I have computed a javascript map that I'd like import as a module in the browser. I could write the data to disk and then read it back with e.g https://github.com/webpack/json-loader, but is there any more elegant ways to do this in-memory?

webpack.config:

```
var config = {
  key: 'data'    
}
// do something with webpack loaders
```

some.file.that.is.executed.in.browser.js:

```
var config = require('config')
window.alert('Config is', config.key)
```

Answer (score 2):

webpack loaders are file preprocessor, thus there needs to be the file that you import. So create a dummy file and use [json-string-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-string-loader) to override the contents.

Create an empty `config.json` to your project.

In webpack.config.js:

```
var appConfig = {
  key: 'data'
}
...
loaders: [
{
    test: /config.json$/,
    loader: 'json-string-loader?json=' + JSON.stringify(appConfig)
}
```

In browser:

```
var appConfig = require("./config.json");
// => returns {key: 'data'}
```

Comment: It's a very useful package;)

Answer (score 1):

> I could write the data to disk and then read it back with e.g
>   https://github.com/webpack/json-loader, but is there any more elegant
>   ways to do this in-memory?

Why? You can just do whatever you need in *config.js* (instead of static json) and just return a result:

```
var data = 'foo' + 'bar';
module.exports = {
  key: data
}
```

Comment: In this case you not even needed to use loaders, by the way.

Comment: lets say I have in my `index.js`: `var version = require("package.json").version;` , but I don't want to load entire **package.json**, I need just version. So, I am going to generate replacement for `package.json` on build-time